# Can't modify WordPress users list in the admin dasboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently trying to modify the name column in the WordPress admin dashboard. I've tried this code here but it's not working:

```
add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'modify_users_column_content', 10, 3 );
function modify_users_column_content( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {

    if ( $column_name === 'name' ) {
        $value .= '<span> |</span>';
    }

    return $value;
}
```

When I `error_log` the `column_name` parameter, I get only the last two columns from the user management plugin UltimateMember:

[image]

The first columns are not within the array. I've tried to understand it but no chance. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first columns are not within the array. I've tried to understand
>   it but no chance. I don't get it.

Because the `manage_users_custom_column` filter is meant to be used to generate the output of a *custom* column and not default columns like the "Name" column.

However, you can achieve what you want by replacing the default "Name" column (keyed `name`) with a custom one like so:

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', function( $columns ){
    $columns2 = [];

    // We could do $columns['name2'] = 'Name'; - but we are replacing a column.
    foreach ( $columns as $key => $label ) {
        if ( 'name' === $key )
            $columns2['name2'] = 'Name';
        else
            $columns2[ $key ] = $label;
    }

    return $columns2;
} );
```

And then use the `manage_users_custom_column` filter to generate the output which is displayed in the custom column (`name2`):

```
add_filter( 'manage_users_custom_column', function( $output, $column_name, $user_id ){
    if ( 'name2' === $column_name ) {
        $user_object = get_userdata( $user_id );
        $name = trim( $user_object->first_name . ' ' . $user_object->last_name );
        $output = $name ? $name . '<span> |</span>' : '&#8212;'; // the custom output
    }
    return $output;
}, 10, 3 );
```